# Python Pickle Error For Multiprocessing Manager Sharing Lists

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pickle

I am trying to populate lists self.images and self.servers with functions self.refresh_images_list and self.refresh_server_list using multiprocessing. I am doing this so when the object is created they will kick off async. I am using shared lists so the child copy will update the original objects list.

However, I am getting a Pickle error so I am pretty stuck.

```
class Account():
    def __init__(self, username, api, pipe_object):
        manager = Manager()
        self.images = manager.list()
        self.servers = manager.list()
        self.images_timestamp = None
        self.servers_timestamp = None
        #needed a dictionary instead of 
        #list/tuple. This works best for 
        #the generator.
        self.regions = {
                "DFW" : pyrax.connect_to_cloudservers("DFW"),
                "ORD" : pyrax.connect_to_cloudservers("ORD"),
                "SYD" : pyrax.connect_to_cloudservers("SYD")
                }
    p1 = Process(target = self.refresh_server_list, args=())
    p2 = Process(target = self.refresh_image_list, args=())
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()

    flavors = None
    #multiprocessing shares lists only for __init__
    #after __init__, we want to break the share
    unshare_lists = False


    def refresh_server_list(self):
    if self.unshare_lists:
        self.servers = []
        self.servers_timestamp = time.strftime(
            "%I:%M:%S", time.localtime()
        )
        with Redirect(self.pipe_object):
            print "\nRefreshing server cache...hold on!"

        for region, value in self.regions.iteritems():
            region_servers = value.servers.list()
            for region_servers in generator(region_servers, region):
                self.servers.append(region_servers)

        with Redirect(self.pipe_object):
            print "\nServer cache completed!"

    def server_list(self):
        if not self.servers:
            self.refresh_server_list()

        with Redirect(self.pipe_object):
            print_header("Cached Server List", "-")
            for srv in self.servers:
                print "\nName: %s" % srv.name
                print "Created: %s" % srv.created
                print "Progress: %s" % srv.progress
                print "Status: %s" % srv.status
                print "URL: %s" % srv.links[0]["href"]
                print "Networks: %s" % srv.networks
            print "\nLast Refresh time: %s" % self.servers_timestamp

    def refresh_image_list(self):
    if self.unshare_lists:
        self.images = []
        self.images_timestamp = time.strftime(
            "%I:%M:%S", time.localtime()
        )
        with Redirect(self.pipe_object):
           # print_header("Active Image List", "-")
            print "\nRefreshing image cache...hold on!"

        for region, value in self.regions.iteritems():
            region_images = value.images.list()
            for region_images in generator(region_images, region):
                self.images.append(region_images)

        with Redirect(self.pipe_object):
            print "\nImage cache completed!"

    def image_list(self):
        if not self.images:
            self.refresh_image_list()

        with Redirect(self.pipe_object):
            print_header("List Images", "-")
            for img in self.images:
                print (
                    str(self.images.index(img)+1) + ") "
                    + "Name: %s\n    ID: %s Status: %s" %
                    (img.name, img.id, img.status)
                    )
            print "\nLast Refresh time: %s" % self.images_timestamp
```

The error I get:

```
Refreshing server cache...hold on!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "menu.py", line 162, in <module>
    main()
  File "menu.py", line 156, in main
    menus[value](hash_table, accounts)
  File "menu.py", line 104, in menu
    choices[value]()
  File "/home/work/modules/classes.py", line 87, in server_list
    self.refresh_server_list()
  File "/home/work/modules/classes.py", line 80, in refresh_server_list
    self.servers.append(region_servers)
  File "<string>", line 2, in append
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 758, in _callmethod
    conn.send((self._id, methodname, args, kwds))
cPickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'instancemethod'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.instancemethod failed
```

Comment: The error is quite clear: you cannot pickle instance methods. Read carefully what you [can and can't pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled). This has implications in `multiprocessing` since it communicates using pickling. The problem seems to be that your `self.regions` dictionary has methods as values.

Comment: Actually, the self.regions list has objects so that makes sense. Would pipes or Ques use pickling also?

Comment: Yes, they would. You have to work around this limitation in some way.
For example, instead of passing methods you could insert functions defined at the top level of the module and pass the instance on which you'd like to call the method explicitly.